# How to poll asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync (Vision API) using getMetadata() - Java

Tags: long-polling, google-cloud-vision, vision

I am parsing a large PDF using Google Vision API asyncBatchAnnotateFilesAsync using Java
Now I want to poll the request every 1 second to check the current status of the Async annotation request using getMetadata() method for the long-running operation Async call.

If I print(response.GetMetadat()), I get this output :
[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=[com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture@ac76b42[status=PENDING]], function=[com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$ApiFunctionToGuavaFunction@268aa98c]]]

But I want to only capture status (status=PENDING) part of getMetadata(). I am not sure what variable datatype should I declare in Java to capture output of getMetadata() so I could parse it to get just "Status"

Answer (score 1):

`OperationFuture.getMetadata()` offers the [`isDone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) method to check for the completion of the batch job. The method returns  (Boolean) `true` if the job is completed, `false` if the job is running. The job completion may be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation. Refer to the below code sample.

```java
while(!response.getMetadata().isDone()){
    System.out.println("In Progress...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // One second delay
}
```

However, if you want to parse the returned protobuf message, the `toString()` method can be used. The output of `response.getMetadata().toString()` is a string that can be checked for the presence of `PENDING` as a substring.

```java
while(response.getMetadata().toString().contains("PENDING")) // Checking if the job is in the pending state.
{
    System.out.println("In Progress...");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // One second delay
}

if(response.getMetadata().toString().contains("SUCCESS"))
{
    System.out.println("\nProcess Done!");
}

if(response.getMetadata().toString().contains("FAILURE"))
{
    System.out.println("\nProcess Failed!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kabilan, this is very helpful.

Comment: @user3205469 Can you elaborate more on your use case? Is there a specific requirement why you want to store the status in a variable?

Comment: @user3205469 Can you accept the answer if it solved you issue?